# SQL: how to find all local min in column

Tags: sql

There is a table A with 2 columns:

```
id: integer auto increment primary key; 
value: integer
```

Usually the record with bigger "id" has the bigger "value" column, but sometimes "value" column going down. I need to find all records with local minimum in "value" column.

I know how to do it using the cursor and comparing the current record with previous.

I am looking for pure SQL solution

```
SELECT id, value from A order by id
     id value
     -- -----
     1  10
     2  13
     3  9      <-- how to find this record
     4  14 
     5  25
     6  10     <-- how to find this record
     7  78
```

Comment: What's your DBMS? Does it support `LAG/LEAD`?

Answer (score 0):

could be with a self join

```
select A.id, A.value, B.id, B.value from A 
left join b on a.id-1 = b.id and a..value >= b.value
where b.id is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the ANSI standard `lag()` function:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*, lag(value) over (order by id) as prev_value
      from a
     ) a
where prev_value > value;
```

If your definition of local minimum is that it is less than both the preceding and next value:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             lag(value) over (order by id) as prev_value,
             lead(value) over (order by id) as next_value
      from a
     ) a
where value < prev_value and
      (value > next_value or next_value is null);
```

Note:  You might want `<=` (etc.) depending on your definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it as,

select id,value from table_name where 1!=2 and rownum=1 order by value;

Here 'rownum' is just simple index, i have displayed first record